# How to use HTTP status code symbols in RSpec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, http-status-codes, human-readable

I use [HTTP status code symbols](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v4.0.0/guides/source/layouts_and_rendering.md#the-status-option) in code in a controller such as:

```ruby
render json: {
    auth_token: user.authentication_token, 
    user: user
  }, 
  status: :created
```

or

```ruby
render json: {
    errors: ["Missing parameter."]
  }, 
  success: false, 
  status: :unprocessable_entity
```

In the code of  my request spec I also would like to use the symbols:

```ruby
post user_session_path, email: @user.email, password: @user.password
expect(last_response.status).to eq(201)
```

...

```ruby
expect(last_response.status).to eq(422)
```

However each test where I use the symbols instead of integers fails:

```shell
Failure/Error: expect(last_response.status).to eq(:created)

  expected: :created
       got: 201

  (compared using ==)
```

---

Here is the latest list of [HTTP status code symbols in Rack](https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/master/lib/rack/utils.rb#L581).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

On the one hand, response is built with methods like:

- success?
- redirect?
- unprocessable?
- full list do: `response.methods.grep(/\?/)`

On the other hand, Rspec predicates transforms every `foo?` method to a `be_foo` matcher.

Not sure you can have the 201 this way unfortunately, but creating a custom matcher is quite easy.

Note Rails test only [rely on a few statuses](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/testing/assertions/response.rb#L26).

Comment: I tried `expect(last_response.status).to be_created` which fails with *"undefined method `created?' for 201:Fixnum"*.

Comment: `expect(last_response).to be_success`

Comment: Same: `expect(last_response.status).to be_success` fails with *"undefined method 'success?' for 201:Fixnum"*. I understood that `created?` is not part of the list and experimented with a custom matcher ... w/o success by now though.

Comment: reread what I wrote: `expect(last_response)` not `expect(last_response.status)`

Comment: I admin I did not read your comments so well but this time it fails with *"undefined method `success?' for #<Rack::MockResponse:0x000000058c1180>"*

Comment: why do you have a `<Rack::MockResponse:0x000000058c1180>` it should be a `ActionController::TestResponse`. where do your specs live?

Comment: The request test I am executing is located in `spec/api/sessions_controller_spec.rb`.

Comment: request spec? request specs should live in `spec/features`, controller spec should live in `spec/controllers`, otherwise the wrong modules will be added (unless you include them manually)

Comment: I might misunderstand but [rspec-rails states](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails#request-specs) that request specs belong either in `spec/requests`, `spec/api` or `spec/integration`.

Comment: from your link: `Note that Capybara's DSL as shown is, by default, only available in specs in the spec/features directory`

Comment: Thanks. But when I move the test into `spec/features` it fails with `undefined local variable or method 'app' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Neste..`. The `spec_helper.rb` contains `config.include Rack::Test::Methods, type: :feature` meanwhile. See my updated question now including `post user_session_path ...`.

Comment: in a feature spec you should not bother about `response`, you should work on `page`. `response` is for controllers spec.

Comment: I dont what and how you did but when you do not follow the standard paths, it's normal you stumble upon many issues/

Comment: I guess I am on the wrong way. Can you point to the correct path please to test the response of my API endpoints?

Comment: This shoul be controller specs, and you'd be able to use what I put in my answer

Comment: I am trying to follow your advise and [tutorials like this](http://everydayrails.com/2012/04/07/testing-series-rspec-controllers.html) but I still can't get it running. To avoid further drifting away from my original question [here is a new post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18278326/nameerror-undefined-local-variable-or-method-app).

Comment: I've spent much time on your question without any counterpart, don't expect me to spend more elsewhere. sorry.

Comment: No offense please. I am the last one who forgets to vote on people's help. Though, normally I wait until I the problem is solved in total before I vote or grant the answer flag.

Answer (score 31):

The `response` object responds to several of the symbol types as messages. So you can simply do:

```
expect(response).to be_success
expect(response).to be_error
expect(response).to be_missing
expect(response).to be_redirect
```

For the other types, such as `:created`, you can create a simple custom matcher for this which wraps [`assert_response`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionDispatch/Assertions/ResponseAssertions/assert_response):

```
RSpec::Matchers.define :have_status do |type, message = nil|
  match do |_response|
    assert_response type, message
  end
end

expect(response).to have_status(:created)
expect(response).to have_status(404)
```

This should work fine for controller specs which have the proper state setup. It will **not** work for feature specs. I haven't tried with request specs, so your milage may vary there.

The reason this works is it leverages the fact that RSpec controller specs have similar state setup behind the scenes. So when `assert_response` accesses `@response` it is available.

This matcher can probably be improved by simply copying the code used by `assert_response` into the matcher:

```
RSpec::Matchers.define :have_status do |type, message = nil|
  match do |response|
    if Symbol === type
      if [:success, :missing, :redirect, :error].include?(type)
        response.send("#{type}?")
      else
        code = Rack::Utils::SYMBOL_TO_STATUS_CODE[type]
        response.response_code == code
      end
    else
      response.response_code == type
    end
  end

  failure_message do |response|
    message or
      "Expected response to be a <#{type}>, but was <#{response.response_code}>"
  end
end
```

#### UPDATE: 2014-07-02

This is now available out of the box with RSpec Rails 3: https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/3-0/docs/matchers/have-http-status-matcher

Answer (score 21):

this works for me:

```
expect(response.response_code).to eq(Rack::Utils::SYMBOL_TO_STATUS_CODE[:not_found])
```

Answer (score 14):

With *rspec-rails* (as of *rspec* 3) it's possible to use

```
expect(response).to have_http_status(:created)
```

**Update 2018-06-11**:

As of Rails 6, some of the matchers will be replaced (e. g. `success` by `successful`).

Comment: Only in RSpec version 3 or later.  `have_http_status` is not included in RSpec 2.