# NameError: undefined local variable or method `app'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rack, rspec-rails

The controller spec I created fails with the following error message:

```
NameError: undefined local variable or method `app' for \
  #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1::Nested_1::Nested_1:0x00000004424880>
```

...

```
# spec/controllers/sessions_conroller_spec.rb
require 'spec_helper'

describe SessionsController do

  before do
    @user = User.gen!
  end

  describe "#create" do
    context "when sending valid email and password" do
      it "renders a json hash ..." do
        post :create, email: @user.email, password: @user.password
        expect(last_response.status).to eq(201)
      end
    end
  end

  describe "#destroy" do
    context "when sending valid email and authentication token" do
      it "renders a json hash ..." do
        delete :destroy, email: @user.email, auth_token: @user.authentication_token
        expect(last_response.status).to eq(200)
      end
    end
  end

end
```

The `spec_helper.rb`loads some mix-ins.

```
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'rspec/autorun'
require 'capybara/rspec'
Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each { |f| require f }

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods
  config.include Rack::Test::Methods, type: :controller
  config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"    
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = true
  config.infer_base_class_for_anonymous_controllers = false
  config.order = "random"
end
```

Comment: This might be useful: https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/1068659

Comment: Then I no longer have access to [`last_response`](https://github.com/brynary/rack-test/blob/v0.6.2/lib/rack/mock_session.rb#L55). But you are right: the **first test passes** when I use `response` instead. The "destroy" action test however **fails**: "expected: 200 got: 401" but this might have something to do with the **authentication token**. I wonder how `app` **can be defined**..

Comment: Something like this should solve it? https://gist.github.com/alex-zige/5795358 (Custom Rspec Helper for Rake::Test::Methods for api scopes.)

Comment: I may work but is API testing really so far from [common conventions on controller testing](http://everydayrails.com/2012/04/07/testing-series-rspec-controllers.html)?

Answer (score 10):

I didn't have this configuration as Jeremy says, and still had the error

I solved just adding this to rails_helper.rb

```
  def app
    Rails.application
  end
```

But I'm not sure why is working now, any idea?

Answer (score 8):

Remove the following from your `spec_helper.rb`

```
config.include Rack::Test::Methods, type: :controller
```

Comment: For anyone else banging their heads against the wall getting the "NameError: undefined local variable or method \`app'" error. It also happens when you are running all your tests at once (multiple files) and one of them does an `include Rack::Test::Methods` - the include "infects" the other tests. So the symptom is that all tests pass when the files are run individually, but then they fail with the "no app" error when run together. At least this happens with `rails 3.0.9` and `rspec 3.0`

Comment: @NicoBrenner This is my scenario and I'm having this issue. How did you solve it? Thanks!